# Retrieving columns by column number in an HTML 5 SQL query

Tags: javascript, sql, html

So I have this:

```
db.transaction(function(tx) {
  tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM records", [], function(tx, results) {
    var length = results.row.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      var result = results.row.item(i);
      // print out all the columns of that result
    }
  });
});
```

How do I access the contents of each column in the result? I know that I can just invoke result['column_name'] for each column but what if there's 20 columns? Can't i access it from inside another for loop and use the iterator instead of the column name? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You could iterate over the properties of `result`:

```
var result = results.row.item(i);
for(var column in result) {
    if(!result.hasOwnProperty(column))  // Yes, I'm paranoid.
        continue;
    // The column name is in column, the value is in
    // result[column] so do what needs to be done.
}
```

Comment: It does not work for me, Is var result = results.row(s).item(i) working.

Comment: @M.S.Naidu: I don't know what you mean. Maybe a new question would work better for you.

Comment: var result = results.row(s).item(i), There is no 's' appending for row , Is that syntax works.

Comment: @M.S.Naidu: I don't know off the top of my head, I haven't used this stuff for a long time. Have you checked what is in `result`?

Comment: I am getting, Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'item' of undefined, if i use var result = results.row.item(i);

Comment: can i use that column as a column name to get the row result like: results.rows.item(i).column